# How to set up a getter for my array x and y for my snake?

Tags: arrays, getter

Can anyone help me out im trying to set up a getter for my arrays of X and Y so i can access them in my objects class.

I cant figure out how to do this.

2500 comes from my screen being 500x500 so (500*500) / (10*10)
10*10 is my size of my snakes body and the head.

```
private final int allDots = 2500;

private int[] x = new int[allDots];
private int[] y = new int[allDots];
```

If needed more reference to the code i can post as much as needed just ask.